# css: how to put text between two images side by side?

Tags: html, css

```
        <span><img src="1.png" style="padding-left:10px;float:left;"> 
<img src="2.png" style="margin-left:10px;float:left;"></span>
```

This puts the two images right next to each other, I want to insert a text that says " into... " in the middle. If I try to add the text, it will start a new line for the image.

Comment: That's a really sparse amount of information for us to go on, to provide you an answer. Have you checked to see if other code is causing issues with this? Is there a reason you're using floats on the images and not on the text between the two images? Seems like we could use some more context here.

Comment: Why are you using floats in the first place? Take them out and you get what you describe.

Comment: wow looks like someone went on a downvote bombing raid. upvoted all the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it like this:

```
<span>
<img src="1.png" style="padding-left:10px;float:left;"> 
<i style="float:left; padding-left:10px;"> into... </i>
<img src="2.png" style="margin-left:10px;float:left;">
```

here is working [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axgsww4q/)

Comment: someone went crazy and downvoted all the answers. I upvoted it again

Comment: I just tried it and it put the second image below the text

Comment: Thats good. div is block element actually and span is inline, so div took the full width hence did the trick.
 You can mark as correct if worked.

Answer (score 2):

You could set both as 'display: inline-block' instead of 'float:left'

```
"<span><img src="1.png" style="padding-left:10px;display:inline-block;"> into...
<img src="2.png" style="margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;"></span>"
```

but be aware of vertical-alignment, because you might have to set 'vertical-align: middle' or even 'vertical-align: top' on both images and on the wrapper, in this case the 'span' tag

Comment: this put everything on top of each other

Comment: actually not, see [http://codepen.io/creativelikeadog/pen/Aivae], it will only do that if the span has 'display:block' and the width is smaller than the sum of all widths

Answer (score -1):

try `style="float:left"` for every of your tags. it will make them stick to the left side. if you want them to have space between, set margin

(if you don't understand what i'm saying, you should google css tutorial. it will help you style your websites

Comment: you can't put inline text in between two floated elements.  Also, it appears that he is already floating the images.